# Integrating tomcat and eclipse but fails to test servlet?

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I followed couple of links and i'm still having problem in deploying servlet page.

**Reference Link:** 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html

**Task Accomplished:**
1. Able to integrate tomcat Apache 7.x with Eclipse [ Add the server ]
2. created JSP page to check for current date and time [ Create a sample page ]
3. Deploy the JSP page [ Deploy the page ]

**Problem:**
1. Created the server with package name "de.vogella.wtp.filecounter" and class name"HelloServlet.java".

***followed below mentioned :***
Restart now appears in the Status column next to the Tomcat server. To restart the server, right-click the server in the Servers view, then select Restart > Start. Open a browser and navigate to **http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/HelloServlet** (where de.vogella.wtp.filecounter is the name of your dynamic Web project).

**Error:**
 [image]

**SOLUTION:**

As Balus mentioned, worked perfect

Import :

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

Added before the class declaration & after IMPORT :

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that the URL is wrong or that the servlet is not mapped in `web.xml`. It should match the `<url-pattern>` of the servlet as specified in its `<servlet-mapping>` in `web.xml`.

If it's for example

```
<url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
```

and the context path of your project is indeed really `de.vogella.wtp.filecounter` (strange context path though):

> http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/hello

Or, since you're using Tomcat 7 already, you can also just use the new `@WebServlet` annotation instead, so that you don't need to fiddle with `web.xml` anymore. Put the following annotation on the servlet class:

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
```

This will map the servlet on the URL pattern of `/hello`.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains some hello world examples as well (and are more up to date than those old IBM/Vogella tutorials)